# How can I prevent my GCP VertexAI kernel from constantly disconnecting during notebook runs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

GCP VertexAI kernel disconnects constantly and for no reason I can see>

I am trying to run a notebook in VertexAI, but it disconnects every time within 5-10 mins of launching.

It did work the last few months, but for no reason seems to have now broken and become unusable.